# Stata - regress and estimates store using forvalues

Tags: regression, stata

I've tried to repeat the following process:

```
forvalues i=1990(1)2013 { 
reg a b c if year==`i',r
est sto G`i'
}
```

However, Stata regress and doesn't store the coefficients of each regression. Probably, `forvalues` isn't the best command to do that, but I don't know which coding is better.

Comment: Your problem might be better posed as MCVE. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There is no mention of `esttab` in your question. Note that `est sto` and `eststo` are different commands.

Answer (score 1):

as Nick suggested, here the very obvious solution is

```
ssc install esttab

forvalues i=1990(1)2013 { 
    reg a b c if year==`i', r
    eststo G`i'
}

esttab, ar2
```